# Alternatives to for loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop some objects using for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PersonalIdentityNumber.Count; i++)
{
    var personnummer = PersonalIdentityNumber[i];
    var fornamn = FirstName[i];
    var efternamn = LastName[i];
    var lankod = LanKod[i];
    var kommunkod = Kommunkod[i];
    var postNr = PostNr[i];
    var medborgarskapslandKod = MedborgarskapslandKod[i];
}
```

And get error:

> Index was out of range. It must not be negative and must be smaller
>   than the size the multitude.

The reason I get error is because the object `postNr`has a count of 21 where the primary `PersonalIdentityNumber` has 24.

Are there alternatives I can use instead of the `for` loop in this situation? The problem with the `for` loop is that the object cannot be less than the primary(in this case `PersonalIdentityNumber`)

**UPDATE 3**

My entire code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace TESTMAPPNING2
{
    class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //try
            //{

            List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();


            var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
                .Select(x => new Person
                {
                    PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
                    LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn,
                    FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn,
                    NationalRegistrationCountyCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod,
                    NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod,
                    CitizenshipCode = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod
                    // and so on
                });


           // var PersonalIdentityNumber = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr).ToList();
           // var FirstName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn).ToList();

           // var LastName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn).ToList();
           // var LanKod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod).ToList();
           // var Kommunkod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod).ToList();

           //// var UtdelAdress2 = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2).ToList();
           // var PostNr = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null);

           // //var PostOrt = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Postort).ToList();

           // //var FodelselanKod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.FodelselanKod).ToList();

           // //var Fodelseforsamling = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.Fodelseforsamling).ToList();

           // var MedborgarskapslandKod = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod).ToList();

           // var Medborgarskapsdatum = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Medborgarskap.Medborgarskapsdatum).ToList();


            //var zipped = PersonalIdentityNumber.Zip(FirstName, Tuple.Create);

            //     foreach (var tuple in zipped)
            //     {
            //         //Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
            //         //Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2);
            //     }

            //Console.WriteLine(PersonalIdentityNumber.Count());

            //for (int i = 0; i < PersonalIdentityNumber.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    var personnummer = PersonalIdentityNumber[i];
            //    var fornamn = FirstName[i];
            //        var efternamn = LastName[i];

            //        var lankod = LanKod[i];
            //        var kommunkod = Kommunkod[i];
            //        var utdelAdress2 = UtdelAdress2[i];
            //        var postNr = PostNr[i];
            //        var postOrt = PostOrt[i];
            //        var fodelselanKod = FodelselanKod[i];
            //        var fodelseforsamling = Fodelseforsamling[i];
            //        var medborgarskapslandKod = MedborgarskapslandKod[i];
            //        var medborgarskapsdatum = Medborgarskapsdatum[i];
            //         use your variables


            //}

            //Console.WriteLine(PersonalIdentityNumber.Count());

            //foreach (var i in PersonalIdentityNumber)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + i);

            //    foreach(var a in FirstName)
            //    {
            //        Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + a);
            //    }







            string connetionString = null;


            SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlReader xmlFile;



            connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";


            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                connection.Open();



                DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber", connection);

                foreach (Person p in myPersons)
                {



                    //var personnummer = PersonalIdentityNumber[i];
                    //var fornamn = FirstName[i];
                    //var efternamn = LastName[i];
                    //var lankod = LanKod[i];
                    //var kommunkod = Kommunkod[i];
                    //var utdelAdress2 = UtdelAdress2[i];
                    //var postNr = PostNr[i];
                    //var postOrt = PostOrt[i];
                    //var fodelselanKod = FodelselanKod[i];
                    //var fodelseforsamling = Fodelseforsamling[i];
                    //var medborgarskapslandKod = MedborgarskapslandKod[i];
                    // var medborgarskapsdatum = Medborgarskapsdatum[i];


                    //command1.Parameters.Clear();
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", p.PersonalIdentityNumber);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", p.NationalRegistrationCountyCode);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", p.NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", utdelAdress2);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", postNr);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", postOrt);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", fodelselanKod);
                    ////command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", fodelseforsamling);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", p.CitizenshipCode);
                    //// command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", medborgarskapsdatum);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);



                    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Console.WriteLine(p.PersonalIdentityNumber);


                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

            //}// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
        //   catch (Exception)
        //    {

        //        throw;
        //    }
        //    Console.ReadKey();
        //}

   class Person {
       public string PersonalIdentityNumber { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationCountyCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode { get; set; }
       public string CitizenshipCode { get; set; }
}

    private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // Create an instance of T
        T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("navetout.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
            // to serialize the data from the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        // return the Deserialized data.
        return ReturnListOfT;
    }

    // function to create instance of T
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }





}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
public class Sekretessmarkering
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PersonId")]
public class PersonId
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonNr")]
    public string PersonNr { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr")]
    public string Tilltalsnamnsmarkering { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
public class HanvisningsPersonNr
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
public class Mellannamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
public class Aviseringsnamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Namn")]
public class Namn
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tilltalsnamnsmarkering")]
    public string Tilltalsnamnsmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fornamn")]
    public string Fornamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
    public Mellannamn Mellannamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Efternamn")]
    public string Efternamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
    public Aviseringsnamn Aviseringsnamn { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
public class ForsamlingKod
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
public class Folkbokforing
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsdatum")]
    public string Folkbokforingsdatum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanKod")]
    public string LanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "KommunKod")]
    public string KommunKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
    public ForsamlingKod ForsamlingKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fastighetsbeteckning")]
    public string Fastighetsbeteckning { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FiktivtNr")]
    public string FiktivtNr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CareOf")]
public class CareOf
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
public class Utdelningsadress1
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
public class Folkbokforingsadress
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CareOf")]
    public CareOf CareOf { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
    public Utdelningsadress1 Utdelningsadress1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress2")]
    public string Utdelningsadress2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostNr")]
    public string PostNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Postort")]
    public string Postort { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
public class Riksnycklar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FastighetsId")]
    public string FastighetsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AdressplatsId")]
    public string AdressplatsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LagenhetsId")]
    public string LagenhetsId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Adresser")]
public class Adresser
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
    public Folkbokforingsadress Folkbokforingsadress { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
    public Riksnycklar Riksnycklar { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
public class HemortSverige
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FodelselanKod")]
    public string FodelselanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelseforsamling")]
    public string Fodelseforsamling { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
public class Fodelse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
    public HemortSverige HemortSverige { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
public class Medborgarskap
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MedborgarskapslandKod")]
    public string MedborgarskapslandKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskapsdatum")]
    public string Medborgarskapsdatum { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Personpost")]
public class Personpost
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonId")]
    public PersonId PersonId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
    public HanvisningsPersonNr HanvisningsPersonNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Namn")]
    public Namn Namn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
    public Folkbokforing Folkbokforing { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Adresser")]
    public Adresser Adresser { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
    public Fodelse Fodelse { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
    public Medborgarskap Medborgarskap { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FolkbokforingspostTYPE")]
public class FolkbokforingspostTYPE
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
    public Sekretessmarkering Sekretessmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personpost")]
    public Personpost Personpost { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you get FirstName,LastName,LanKod etc?What is PersonalIdentityNumber?

Comment: There is no for loop which will magically find out what is your main/max value. You have to make sure, that the different objects refer to the same base. How is PostNr generated?

Comment: What should happen with postNr, if `i > 20`?

Comment: Of course there is no such method. How should this magic method know what to do when the index `i` is greater 20?

Comment: You should definitly create a class for the data containing all those attributes that belonmg to a person instead of a set of arrays.

Comment: The question is based on a (apparently) wrong assumption that the problem lies in the `for` construct rather than overall code design that got you to this point. Your requirements aren't entirely clear, either.

Comment: isn't there an ID that is being shared throughout all your objects?

Comment: Well, my goal is to assign these values to a database. And I want it to insert one row at the time. So if PostNumbers has no values, it should return `null`

Comment: @HimBromBeere The values have been deserialized from a XML. Sometimes the XML-tags doesnt have values of the PostNumbers and that is why it should return `null` sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the fix to a symptom of your problem, but you would be much better off fixing the real problem: you need to stop using [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array).

Make a class to hold all properties of the object, i.e.

```
class PersonalInfo {
    public int PersonalIdentityNumber { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    ... // and so on
}
```

Make a collection of objects of `PersonalInfo` class. Now you can walk your collection with a `for` loop without fearing that one array is shorter than another one, or even use a `foreach` loop to go through elements without using an index.

**Note:** If you are curious how your arrays get out of sync, it's happening here:

```
var PostNr = deserializedList
    .Where(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null)
    .Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr)
    .ToList();
```

The `Where` clause rejects some `null` entries, so arrays are no longer parallel. You can fix this by removing `Where`, and producing `null`s for some `PostNr`, i.e.

```
var PostNr = deserializedList
    .Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress?.PostNr)
    .ToList();   //                                              ^
```

(that's C# 6 syntax; you could use an explicit `null` check instead if your C# is of an earlier version).

Comment: Although this answer is the only one handling the actual problem instead of the symptoms it does not really solve the issue with different indices. Obviosuly we have 24 `PersonalInfo`-objects which should use 21 different `PostNr`. So the actual question is: how are the duplicate references handled?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The hope here is once OP gets the data organization side of the house in order, he would be in a much better position to identify and fix the problem that lead to his parallel arrays getting out of sync with each other. The shorter array in a group of parallel arrays is an indication of a bug in some other part of OP's code. Using good representation for his data is a first step toward fixing that bug.

Comment: Totally agree on that. I left a comment within the question which clearifies this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've tried that method `var PostNr = deserializedList
    .Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress?.PostNr)
    .ToList();` before and got two errors:
`Invalid expression term '.'` AND `Syntax error, ':' expected`

Comment: @John.P It looks like you've got a C# version below 6. Try `.Select(item => item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress!=null ? item.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null)`

Answer (score 1):

I would first consider the actual design of your app. You should bundle all the data that represents an entity within your database to a new class, for instance `Person`:

```
class Person {
    public int PersonalIdentityNumber { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    // ...
}
```

When you used XmlSerialization to get the data you won´t even need all those messy arrays and can simply deserialize to an instance of `Person`- regardless if the `PostNr`-tag is set or not.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
Person p = (Person) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

This will automatically assign `null` (or whatever the default-value for the type is) to those attributes which are not set within the xml.

EDIT: When you already have a list of type `FolkbokforingspostTYPE` containing all the information you need why do you store the values in seperate lists at all. You may simply use this:

```
var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
    .Select(x => new Person 
        {
            PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
            LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn,
            FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.ForNamn
            NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = (Personpost.Adresser == null || Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress == null) ?
                null: 
                Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2)
         });
```

EDIT2: With this list you can now simply create and execute your Sql-statements:

```
foreach(Person p in myPersons) 
{
    command1.Parameters.Clear();
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", p.PersonalIdentityNumber);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName);
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName);

    command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(personnummer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does `Person` come from in your example?

Comment: It is a new class that holds the data for exactly one entity within your database.

Comment: Alright thanks. Now when I think about it, the reason why I created each list 
separate was because I need to assign them to the database table as you can see in my code. Would this method that you provided work for that?

Comment: Sure, you simply loop the list of `Person` instead of `PersonalIdentityNumber` and get the properties directly from the current entity. Now you can simply put the properties value into your SQL-statement.

Comment: How do I get the properties from the current entity? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and get error:  The variable name `'@PersonalIdentityNumber' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.` when trying to run it

Comment: I updated my question with how my entire code looks like right now.

Comment: Now the problem is that a value in `var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
    .Select(x => new Person 
        {
            PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
            LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn,
            FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.ForNamn
            // and so on
         });` can have a null. How can I make it just return a null and move on without an error?

Comment: Have you tried this? The `Select`statement should simply set the property to null and continue without any error. What error do you get and where do you get it?

Comment: Yeah I tried it and got error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I got the error on:
 `NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2,
                    NationalRegistrationPostCode = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr,` because they can sometimes contain `null`

Comment: Debug through and break on every exception, I bet the exception occurs because any of those inermediate properties of `x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress` (or similar) is null. So either `Adresser` or `Folkbokforingsadress`.

Comment: In both cases you have to ensure that the properties are not null before assigning their value to your `Person`: `Select(x => new Person { NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = (x.Personpost.Adresser != null && NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2.Folkbokforingsadress != null) ? NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2: null`

Comment: Well yeah that is the problem. `Folkbokforingsadress` IS null is some cases. I'm wondering if I can do anything to make the code run without the error.

Comment: I tried that method but got error: `The name 'NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2' does not exist in the current context`